# MacBook Pro Early 2015 13" temperature

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

Last week I bought new MacBook Pro 13", early 2015, core i5, 8GB RAM, and now I am a little bit worried about it's temperature. It's my first MacBook, so I don't really know what temperatures should I expect.

I am getting 50°C - 60°C (CPU) when browsing the web, while having multiple tabs opened (Google Chrome) and Dropbox running in the background.

I don't know if these are okay, the bottom side of MacBook seems a little warm on touch.

Maybe I am a little bit overcautious, but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely 100% perfectly fine!

My MBP temp is regularly between 66 and 81 degrees, and my fans are regularly at 6200 RPM when my CPU usage is high.

Also, this [resource](https://www.intelmactemp.com/list) (which can be filtered) clearly shows that 50°C - 60°C is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I was getting the same temps. Normal, I think, but I was unhappy with them so I replaced the thermal compound that had dried up with Arctic Silver and now it idles around 40 c and 46 c while tasked with pretty much everything until I open up a game, or the Adobe Suite and start doing work. Final Cut also puts the temperature up. Sometimes it hits 50. If you're worried about it, you can get it assessed for free at the genius bar.